# Drupal configuration on non root url (how to change $base_url)?

Tags: uri

sorry for my english, I'm french

ok, that's I want to do is to install my drupal site on a url like : 
www.mymachine.fr/mydrupal/

and the problem is that when I go this url, 
he dispatch me to www.mymachine.fr/core/install.php
instead of www.mymachine.fr/mydrupal/core/install.php

so the install doesn't work

My conf is like this : debian server

in drupal file "sites.php", I have this :

$sites['mymachine.fr.mydrupal'] = 'mydrupal';

on /etc/hosts, I add this line  : 
    127.0.0.1    mymachine.fr.mydrupal

on /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mymachine.fr.mydrupal
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mydrupal/CORE-DRUPAL8-WEB/web

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    # Log configuration
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/drupal-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/drupal-access.log combined

    <Directory "/var/www/mydrupal/CORE-DRUPAL8-WEB/web">
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

SO I don't know if it's drupal configuration or apache configuration to change $base_url from drupal site ...
thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If your drupal installation resides on the webserver in a subfolder of the webroot for *www.mymachine.fr*, you can set the base path in the drupal site's .htaccess file.

- Find the line that reads `# RewriteBase /drupal`
- Uncomment it by deleting the "#" `RewriteBase /drupal`
- Edit it to reflect your subpath/subfolder `# RewriteBase /mydrupal`

That block should look like this after the edits.

```
# Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
# VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
# For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
# modify the following line:
RewriteBase /mydrupal
```

Then, reset your .conf (vhost entry) to reflect just the top level website (code sample below resets to default .conf setup):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mymachine.fr.mydrupal
  DocumentRoot /var/www

  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

  # Log configuration
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

  <Directory "/var/www">
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This setup presumes that your top level domain does not have any redirection rules that forward/process all requests (such as the rules in an out-of-the-box Drupal or Wordpress .htaccess for processing requests with index.php)  If your top level domain has such a redirect rule in place, you may need to add another rule to exclude your mydrupal subdirectory.